# Store Meta Data to Site

Tags: php, wordpress, data-structures

I'm looking for a away to assign some meta data to a site in WP multisite, just like you can do to a post with add_post_meta().

I want to store some data like a mail address, a link, an array of activated languages and so on.

Anyone a recommendation what's best practise to save stuff like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the information like email address , links , array of activated languages inside the wp_options(default prefix) table. All you need to look in to [Options API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API)

store the options with `add_option()` and `update_option()` and retrieve the options via `get_option()`

This will be useful for multisite installation also. Here is the guide to [setup](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/multisite-settings/)